# Why pushing object to array causes Gulp Uglify to crash

Tags: javascript, gulp, uglifyjs

I have gulpfile which is supposed to minify my js files normally. I have one function, which runs each loop having following line:

```
newArr.push({[keyName]:val});
```

This one particular line causes the uglify to fail.

The whole function is this:

```
function convertArrToNestedObjArr(arr, keyName) {

    var newArr = [];
    if(arr) {

        $.each(arr, function(k, val) {

            newArr.push({[keyName]:val});
        })
    }
    return(newArr);
}
```

Gulp process gives the following error:

> stream.js:94
>         throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
>               ^ Error
>       at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at ...

Comment: What is `[keyName]`?

Comment: @Philipp: It's in the half-marked-up code, it's an argument to the enclosing function. That notation is ES2015's *computed property name* notation. So the OP must be using Node v4 or higher (or if not, that's part of the problem).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry for being unclear. This is one of the js files my gulp process tries to minify/uglify. But it causes the gulp process to crash.

Comment: @JaakkoKarhu: Ah! That explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said this code is in a file destined to send to a browser that's being uglified in a gulp process.

That line is using ES2015's *computed property name* notation. I suspect the minifier just doesn't understand that yet. If it does, a fair number of browser JavaScript engines in the wild don't, yet.

If that's the problem, transpile before uglifying (perhaps with Babel or Traceur), or replace

```
newArr.push({[keyName]:val});
```

with

```
var o = {};
o[keyName] = val;
newArr.push(o);
```